# Las imágenes en un "CarouselSlider" se vuelven invisibles al abrir mi aplicación

Tags: flutter, imagen, vscode, dart, aplicación-movil

este es mi codigo, tengo un carousel slider en el que tengo varias imagenes, cuando ejecuto esto en el navegador se ve bien, pero al momento de hacer mi apk o simular en un celular fisico, no se ven las imagenes, unicamente se ve el texto.

```
CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            enableInfiniteScroll: true,
            aspectRatio: 2.0,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayInterval: const Duration(milliseconds: 4500),
            autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
            viewportFraction: 0.8,
            autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          ),
          items: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage("assets/imagen1.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: const <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'segunda',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'imagen',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage("assets/imagen4.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: const <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'quinta imagen',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

dentro de cada container coloque una imagen y un texto, soy nuevo en flutter y la verdad no se si la forma en la que lo hice es la correcta, si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar el problema o a optimizar el codigo, se los agradeceria enormemente.

tengo mas contenedores, pero para no hacerlo tan tedioso y grande, borre 3.

Comment: Estas usando NetworkImage que crea un objeto en base a una imagen de una URL , revisa la respuesta de  Jonathan Perez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `NetworkImage` estás pasando un parámetro que no es el correcto, en el `NetworkImage` van únicamente `URL` de imágenes y le estás pasando un asset, utiliza el `Widget AssetImage`:

```
 AssetImage("assets/imagen4.png"),
```

Comment: gracias, me ayudo